# Google Cloud Storage Post File Upload Error

Tags: php, curl, storage, gcloud, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage for a couple days.

upload.php

```
$filedata = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$filesize = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"];

$authheaders = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer [My token]",
    "Content-Type: image/jpeg",
    "Content-Length:".$filesize
); 

    $uploadRequest = array(
       'file' => file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])
    );


$url="https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=".$filename;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $uploadRequest);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $authheaders);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
```

main.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

Uploading was OK. but it' always show black image.
Even though it has size of image(682.72KB)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GVXy.png)

Please save me in whole black image :(

Here is google cloud storage example with curl
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

Comment: Anyone? please??!! :(